# Laravel Component with Laravel Breeze/AlpineJS not working inside <td> but working fine outside

Tags: html, laravel, components, alpine.js

With Laravel 9, using laravel breeze, I have a blade component that's a button with a modal prompt that's show on click.
When the component is called in a <td> tag, @click.outside="open = false" @close.stop="open = false" aren't added like they should, but the component works just fine outside of the <td> tag.

**What the broswer render**

[image: Rendered HTML]

**Code for the the component in question**

```html
@props(['route', 'idSupprimer' => null])

<div x-data="{ open: false }" @click.outside="open = false" @close.stop="open = false">
    <x-button @click="open = ! open" :palette="'danger'" type="button">{{ $trigger }}</x-button>

    <div x-show="open"
         x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
         x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0"
         x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100"
         x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
         x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100"
         x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0"
         style="display: none; background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.5)"
         class="h-screen w-screen absolute top-0 left-0 flex justify-center items-center">
        <div class="rounded-md ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white p-6">
            <div>
                {{$message}}
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-center">
                <x-button @click="open = false" class="mx-1 bg-gray-400" :palette="'principale'" type="button">Annuler</x-button>
                @if($idSupprimer)
                    <x-link-button href="{{ route($route, $idSupprimer) }}" class="mx-1 bg-red-600" :palette="'principale'">{{ $trigger }}</x-link-button>
                @else
                    <x-link-button href="{{ route($route) }}" class="mx-1 bg-red-600" :palette="'principale'">{{ $trigger }}</x-link-button>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And code for where it's used**

```html
<table id="app" class="table-auto w-full text-center text-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Correspondance Clara</th>
        <th>Id Unite Responsable Brio</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @forelse($unitesOrg as $uniteOrg)
        <tr class="border-solid border-t-8 border-b-8 border-white hover:bg-fondBleu odd:bg-white even:bg-slate-100">
            <td>{{$uniteOrg->nom}}</td>
            <td>{{$uniteOrg->id_clara}}</td>
            <td>{{$uniteOrg->id_unite_brio}}</td>
            <td class="flex justify-center">
                <x-link-button href="{{ route('uniteOrgClara.edit', $uniteOrg->id_clara) }}" class="mr-2" :palette="'principale'">Modifier</x-link-button>
                <!--- NOT WORKING --->
                <x-modal-supprimer :route="'uniteOrgClara.destroy'" :idSupprimer="$uniteOrg->id_clara">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        Supprimer
                    </x-slot>
                    <x-slot name="message">
                        Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette unité?
                    </x-slot>
                </x-modal-supprimer>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--- WORKING --->
        <x-modal-supprimer :route="'uniteOrgClara.destroy'" :idSupprimer="$uniteOrg->id_clara">
            <x-slot name="trigger">
                Supprimer
            </x-slot>
            <x-slot name="message">
                Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette unité?
            </x-slot>
        </x-modal-supprimer>
    @empty
        <tr>
            <td colspan="18" class="py-6 text-base">Il n'y a aucune correspondance présentement. <x-link-button class="ml-2" href="{{ route('uniteOrgClara.create') }}" :palette="'principale'">Ajouter une correspondance</x-link-button></td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did  a quick test and it works perfectly for me. Are you shure you are calling the right component?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the reason, it's because AlpineJs and VueJs do not really work togheter. I removed VueJs from my project for now.

Comment: Would suggest never using `@click` but `x-on:click` to prevent issues